# Route all packets on port 80 from inside a vm to kali linux on another vm

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, iptables, forwarding

I'm trying to route all packets on port 80 to kali linux so that I can ssl strip them but I cannot see to setup the iptables correctly to force all the packets to go to my other Vm.

[ Virtual Machine #1]  ---------------------------- > [ Virtual Machine #2 ]
                     route all packets on port 80

Information
-Im using vbox both Vm's are using NAT

Things I've Tried

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 #to enable port forwarding

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.15:80

10.0.2.15 was the inet addr of my kali linux but idk what happened they now both have the same ip addr. I think i screwed something up while messing with it

My Vm network configurations #2 (The one that is taking all the routed packets)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a7:ff:7a
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea7:ff7a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17769462 (16.9 MiB)  TX bytes:262897 (256.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:234701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:234701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:33563198 (32.0 MiB)  TX bytes:33563198 (32.0 MiB)

My Vm network configurations #1 (The one that needs to route all of its packets to other one)

eth10     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:65:07:56
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe65:756/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4828213 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:315305 (315.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1913 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:1913 (1.9 KB)

Comment: Please [edit] and add detail of what you have done so far

Comment: Sorry, you want to get NAT from interface with IP 10.0.2.15 to VM with interface IP 10.0.2.15? The hell?